# ハイフン (-) で始まるファイルを mv するには？

Tags: ubuntu, shellscript, unix

slack でダウンロードしたテキストスニペットは、デフォルトでは `-.txt` で作成される様子です。これをコマンドラインから `mv` しようとしたところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
 % mv -.txt hoge.txt
mv: invalid option -- '.'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

どうやら、ハイフン(<kbd>-</kbd>) で始まるために、オプション引数であると解釈されている様子です。

## 質問

どうやったら、ハイフンから始まるファイルを mv できますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mv -- -.txt hoge.txt
```

と `--` を指定するとそれ以降は`-`をオプションと認識しなくなります

Answer (score 6):

```
mv ./-.txt hoge.txt
```

ファイル名の前にディレクトリ(`./`)を指定すればよいのでは。